# Change ControlTemplate dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate, resourcedictionary, dynamic-usercontrols

There is a template:

```
<Window.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Class1">
        <objs:Class1 FontSize="12" x:Name="class1"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

It consists of a UserControl. I apply it like this:

```
<local:MyThumb Width="120" Height="70" x:Name="myThumb1" Canvas.Left="270" Canvas.Top="60" Template="{StaticResource Class1}"/>
```

The question is how to get this UserControl from the code and change its properties, such as Background for example.

Comment: Use triggers in the control template, or write a style which applies the template and also has triggers. To do it with a style, you'll want to use template bindings in the ControlTemplate so that the properties will be used: `<objs:Class1 FontSize="12" x:Name="class1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />`. What is the target of this template? How is it being used? This doesn't look like a normal usage of the WPF template feature.